# Ubuntu 22:04LTS, Natural Scroll not working for touchpad, Lenovo Yoga

Tags: lenovo, 22.04

Recently updated to ubuntu 22:04LTS, but the natural scroll is not working even though in the settings it is ON

```
> gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad left-handed 'mouse'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad speed 1.0
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag-lock false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-button-map 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true
```

I think non of the settings are not reflectings as in UI I tried turning off the touchpad ass well.

The touchpad is not listed in dconf editor.

[DConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMk4x.png)

Comment: I am having this problem as well on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Tablet running Ubuntu 22.04 and using xorg rather than wayland (becuase there are things not working in wayland)